# Is there a way to extract all bins assigned using the test_ids gem?

Tags: origen-sdk

We use the [test_ids gem](https://github.com/Origen-SDK/test_ids) to handle our binning assignment and it works great.  We use that information to create some 3rd party files versus using the native ATE binning.  The issue arises when we pass multiple flow files to the 'program' command.

```
origen p func_cpu_flow.rb func_gpu_flow.rb
```

In between flow generation the test interface gets reset and the binning information it knows about gets lost.  Is there an API in the test_ids gem that would return a hash with keys being the test names and values being the bin information?  Then I could call this method on the last flow file generation event and create the 3rd party files.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really provide anything like that today, though if you reach in this should be close to what you want:

```
TestIds.current_configuration.allocator.store['assigned']['bins']
TestIds.current_configuration.allocator.store['manually_assigned']['bins']
```